# Constructible decimals?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

So I have to figure out if $1.23456$ is constructible. I think that it's not constructible since:

I know that this is $\frac{123456}{100000}$ so this goes into $\frac{2^6*3*643}{2^55^5}$ and the Fermat Primes are repeated in the denominator so then it's not constructible.

Am I overthinking this? Is it constructible?

Comment: You can construct any rational number...

Comment: @MichaelBiro Oh... well then.. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBiro If she is taking the angle $1.23456 \pi,$ it is not constructible. Not clear what is meant, but the mention of Fermat Primes suggests angles. The part about $5$ being repeated is also correct in that context

Comment: @WillJagy Sure, a different question might have a different answer. My interpretation was that the question was on 1.23456 and the poster just misunderstood what that entails.

Comment: @MichaelBiro Sure, but if you believe the poster is confused why not point it out and ask for elaboration? Why give an answer you know to be misleading? If you understand the intent and the spirit of the question, you cant even suggest an edit?   How many social credit points do you think that earns you here with people like myself?

Answer (score 1):

All rational numbers are constructible.

In sum, constructible numbers are numbers of the form $x+iy$, with $x, y$ as elements of $ℝ$, and $i^2=-1$, where $x$ and $y$ are solutions to linear and quadratic equations with constructible coefficients.

Equivalently, constructible numbers are complex numbers that can be derived from integers with a finite number of arithmetic operations, square root extractions, and complex conjugations.

What you were thinking of is whether or not an angle that is a rational multiple of a full circle is constructible. This is where Fermat primes come into play. Such angles are only constructible if they are the ratio of a full circle and the product of a power of 2 and distinct Fermat primes.